# Cannot get PHPUnit working on Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I am working with Symfony 2 and trying to get PHPunit to work with it so I've added this to my composer.json under required-dev:

```
"phpunit/phpunit": "4.6.*"
```

runned this command in my terminal:

```
composer update --dev
```

after doing the above PHPUnit appears under the `vendor` directory.

According to the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html) Symfony 2 has PHPUnit pre configured and can be executed by: `phpunit -c app/`

But it never works and my terminal message is:

```
 Unknown command “phpunit”
The program 'phpunit' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install phpunit
```

Even through this `./bin/phpunit -c app` seems to trigger phpunit no matter what test I write I always get this:

```
Configuration read from /home/tomazi/Dev/api.test/app/phpunit.xml.dist



Time: 66 ms, Memory: 4.25Mb

No tests executed!
```

My Test:

```
<?php

namespace BoltMail\User\InteractionBundle\Tests\Dto\Template;

class TestTemplateTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testIndex()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: What directories are being searched in: phpunit.xml.dist

Comment: Depending on  the configuration the local (to the project, installed by Composer) phpunit executable may be in the `./bin/` or `vendor/bin/` directories. This is set by an (optional) `bin` json configuration in composer.json. The default is to put executable commands into `vendor/bin/`

Answer (score 3):

as you installed phpunit from composer you should run it from the project directory as

```
$./bin/phpunit -c app
```

or if you want it be runned globally:

> For a system-wide installation via Composer, you can run:
>
> composer global require "phpunit/phpunit=3.7.*" Make sure you have
>   ~/.composer/vendor/bin/ in your path.

**Update to your question:**

I suppose that you already solved the issue with empty tests by specifying target of tests. Just second way is specify target at app/phpunit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit
    backupGlobals               = "false"
    backupStaticAttributes      = "false"
    colors                      = "true"
    convertErrorsToExceptions   = "true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions  = "true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions = "true"
    processIsolation            = "false"
    stopOnFailure               = "false"
    syntaxCheck                 = "false"
    verbose                     = "true"
    bootstrap                   = "bootstrap.php.cache" >
<!-- more settings here -->
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="My Test Suite">
            <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
      <whitelist>
        <directory>../src</directory>
        <exclude>
            <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
            <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
            <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
        </exclude>
      </whitelist>
    </filter>    
</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 1):

You either have to specify your directories in your phpunit config file phpunit.xml.dist or run the command with specific directory or file

```
./bin/phpunit -c app/ path/to/your/test/folder
```